# const correctness when don't be afraid of don't using it

Tags: c++, constants

Sometimes I need to pass the reference of an object. I know the benefits of const correctness in order to avoid modifications in an object and to avoid a mess, but sometimes it's really hard to use it. If I pass an object to a method that is const correct and I call another method that doesn't accept any argument and don't modify the object itself and returns nothing it complains that I need to put it as const as well. And then I'm seeing my whole application getting "const" on the end of the methods even when it returns nothing or get nothing as arguments.

```
void doNothing() const {}
```

I understand that the compiler needs to make sure that any method isn't going to modify the object but this seems to be silly.

My question is: Should I always use const correct or there's a time that I can avoid using and pass an object as reference without being concern of what can happen?

And if has a theory behind it, please explain.

Comment: If the intent of the member function is to modify the object then don't declare it `const`. If the intent is to not modify the object declare it `const`. Not sure what the confusion is here.

Comment: Maybe you can provide an example?

Comment: That third-sentance on, I *think*, could be shortened up to simply say, "sometimes I find I need to call a non-const member from a const-member, and its a pita. If you find most of your members are const, that isn't a bad thing. Nor is it just for programatic protection. Ex: Turning a modern optimizer loose on const-correct code *can* have significant upsides.

Comment: @WhozCraig - Sorry for my ignorance, but can you explain this better? You think that if an application has most of its member as const isn't a bad thing? A reason? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For freestanding functions, you should mark reference and pointer parameters as `const` if the function doesn't modify the parameters. You don't need to do anything for parameters that are passed by value.

For non-static class methods, there's also an implicit `this` parameter. You should mark the method itself as `const` if it doesn't modify `this`. Doing so allows you to call that method on `const` objects. If you don't mark a method as `const` then you can only call it on non-`const` objects.

```
class Foo
{
    int foo;

public:
    void doNothing() const
    {
        foo = 42;    // not allowed: `this` is const
    }
};
```

The hidden `this` parameter is why it matters, even when a method takes no other parameters. It's the hidden parameter that you're protecting.

Answer (score 2):

If something does not modify your object make it `const`. One simple reason to do it: You cannot call a non-`const` member function on a `const` object. That is obviously because non-`const` member function are a allowed to change their instance, while a `const` instance cannot be changed. So making a function non-`const` without need produces logically flawed code: Why, for example, should it be illegal to print a `const Matrix`? That just does not make sense, so a print function for a matrix should be `const`.

This applies to free functions too: Temporaries can only bind to `const` references, not to non-`const` references. So the former is just more general.

And last but not least: The only drawback you mention is writing `const` over and over. So I ask you: How long does it take you to type `const`? Surely not long enough to accept a design flaw in your program.

Comment: When it comes to API and we don't know what the user can do with certain things is better to avoid a mess and that is the reason of const correctness right? When you pass an object to a method that you don't know what it does better it be const correctness and you know that it isn't going to modify anything then throwing your object into the darkness. The question is about calling methods that does nothing but must to be const correctness as well, but as mentioned above the real thing is about the hidden 'this'.
Still thing that it's a bad design just because of const in some methods?